# Can't access OpenStack's Horizon dashboard on 8000 from outside

Tags: virtualbox, nat, openstack

I am using the dashboard on port 8000 using the 
`python manage.py runserver` command because the problem showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276235/open-new-page-from-horizon-login-works-only-if-the-service-is-started-manually)

On localhost it works, but if I try to access it from outside, it doesn't work. Why?

This is my situation:

- Guest machine with ubuntu and OpenStack at address 10.0.2.15 with NAT
  networking
- Host machine with windows and VirtualBox
- Port forwarding done on virtualbox to 10.0.2.15:8000 (it works for others ports but not for 8000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horizon is a Django app, and the django runserver command binds only to localhost by default. If you want it to be accessible from outside, do:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```